# Connect to device over ethernet port

Tags: networking, windows-10, ip

I am trying to to connect to a Hardware Debugger. It's method of connection is an Ethernet port. It has two states, one where you can connect to it using a hostname if it is on a network that supports DHCP and the other is a static IP that is pre-determined (192.168.0.10).

I am trying to connect to it directly using my laptop without any intermediate devices.The laptop ethernet port is directly connected to the port on the debugger with an ethernet cable. There are solid green lights on both ports.

I have configured my ethernet adapter to use a static IP of 192.168.0.20.
[Here is a pic of the ethernet config settings (using a link instead of image since my rep is <10).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7wHo.png)
I am pulling my internet through my wifi adapter. I did a very similar setup to connect to a raspberry pi, so I am pretty sure that the general concept works.

I cannot get it to connect, but this might be because of the Debuggers app is doing something weird. Is there a way for me to test that over the ethernet port I am able to talk to this device? Or is there something I need to change in my ethernet configuration?

I did try using ping from the cmd prompt and it timed out.

I fixed the mask value to be 255.255.255.0. I must've messed it up one of the times I was playing with those settings.

I tried the reset on the debugger, this caused my VPN connection to disconnect and reconnect. I tried turning that off and pinging the device. It worked once and then didn't work again. Then I turned off the wifi and I could connect/ping the device consistently!

Thanks to dirkt's comment I looked at the WLAN gateway and sure enough it is

```
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : redacted
                                   192.168.0.1
```

If someone puts an answer along the lines of "yes ping is the correct command and try turning off other networking devices to test." I will accept it since it answers my original question. Is this a correct thing to say?

Comment: Have you tried it with something serving DHCP? And does it have a way to factory reset it? (I.e reset jumper or push button).

Comment: Have you tried adding the debugger's IP as your gateway yet?

Comment: If your local WLAN also uses a 192.168.*.*, you have a nice address conflict with netmask 255.255.0.0. So make sure your WLAN uses something else than 192.168.0.*, and make that netmask 255.255.255.0. Also, please add an OS tag.

Comment: If you figure out the answer for yourself, you are encouraged to post it as an Answer yourself, and then click the checkmark outline next to it to accept it as the official Answer so the question shows as resolved.